# Extract data from batch file to echo it again?

Tags: batch-file, extract, ping

I just made a very basic batch file to test my ping. I wondered if I can extract the ping and then show it again with echo.
So it looks like this:

Your current ping is: ( Here should be the ping )

Comment: Can you post your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that :

```
@echo off
Title Echo PING Reply by Hackoo
color 0a & mode con cols=57 lines=6
::Choose how many seconds you must wait for the refresh
Set MyPause=8
:MyPing
CLS
echo.
ping www.google.com | findstr /i "TTL"
Timeout /Nobreak /t %MyPause% > Nul
Goto MyPing
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a basic ping request:

@echo off
ping google.com
echo Press any key to close the program
pause>nul